# Includes associated objects without reloading current instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to find a way to load associated objects to my current instance of user.

I've an instance of `user` which I want to pass to a service for business stuff. But this service require to includes associated objects to run fast.

```
user = User.find()
user.email = new_email
SomeService(user)

class SomeService
   def initialize(user)
     user = User.includes(:coupons, :rentals, :rental_demands).find(user.id)
   end
end
```

Doing that reset any changes done on the user instance

Is there any way to do something like :

```
user.includes(:rental_demands)
```

I've tried:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(user, :rental_demands)
```

But it seems to be worst

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader` is right and only way.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader` is not loading scoped objects, its calling every `rental_demands` instead of filtering with the user_id

Comment: Hmm, In Rails 5 I watch only query like `SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE "reports"."member_id" = 11` when call `.preload` on `Member` instance with id 11